# Specific Fox H-function becomes a constatnt function

Tags: probability-or-statistics

The Fox H-function

`FoxH[{{{1/3, 2/3}}, {{1/2, 1/2}}}, {{{0, 1}}, {{1/2, 1/2}}}, x]`

has the same numerical value, 0.431029, at an arbitrary x value.

This specific Fox H-function appears in the $\alpha$-stable probability density function $S(x;\alpha=3/2,\beta=0,\mu=0,\sigma=1)$ when it is written in terms of a Fox H-function. For other applications, I need the mentioned $\alpha$-stable probability density function in terms of a Fox H-function and hence the mentioned specific Fox H-function.

More generaly, for an $0<\alpha<2$ value, i.e., in the case of $S(x;\alpha,\beta=0,\mu=0,\sigma=1)$ the relevant Fox H-function is

`FoxH[{{{1-1/α, 1/α}}, {{1/2, 1/2}}}, {{{0, 1}}, {{1/2, 1/2}}}, x]`

For $0<\alpha<1$ and $\alpha\neq1/2$, it works fine but when $1<\alpha<2$, the above Fox H-function has the same numerical value at an arbitrary x value.

Is this a bug in Wolfram Mathematica or is there a mathematical reason behind it?

Comment: It's not a Bug. So: `FoxH /. \[Beta] -> 0` is not the same as: `Limit[FoxH, \[Beta] -> 0]`. Don't use `Zero` for `, \[Beta] ` , use:`10^50` and `N[FoxH,50]`.Should work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It is working!

Comment: I mean `10^-50`.